# Multiple TikZ keys with foreach

Tags: tikz-pgf, foreach, pgfkeys

Playing around with pgffor, I'm trying to slightly modify an example from the TikZ/pgf manual:

```
\path \foreach \x/\content/\style in {%
  0/a/draw,
  1/b/{draw,red},
  2/c/{circle,blue},
  3/d/draw%
} {
  node[\style] at (\x,0) {\content}
} ;
```

Unfortunately, this does not work for nodes with multiple `\style` options set.
TikZ complains with

> ```
> ! Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/draw,red' and I am going
> to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.
> ```

Now, this works perfectly, when I use a comma separated list for some other variable (e.g. `\content`). So now, my question is: how can I split `\style` while executing the loop? Obviosly, pgf tries to find one key named `draw,red`, when it should be looking for two keys instead, namely `draw` and `red`.

Is there some clever LaTeX macro that correctly expands the loop variable or tells pgf to expect multiple keys?

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but you can define a new name for your comma-separated styles. For example `red drawing/.style={red, draw}` and use this style in your loop.

Comment: Is there a certain reason why you don't like to set up a style an use this? You may say `\tikzset{somekey/.style={draw, red}}` and insert `somekey` instead of the comma-list.

Comment: @JLDiaz, bloodworks: Yep, I used that as a workaround after writing this question, but it is just too unflexible, if you have a lot of different combination of styles (some of which you will only use once)

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/29048/86 as this is about expansion of macros in keys.

Comment: And I'm sure we've had similar questions but my searching skills are severely depleted.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Here's another version, not all that different from the previously supplied but combines them in a slightly different way.  In effect, it is a bit like defining a dynamic style alias that expands to the given list of options.  When a style like `red drawing/.style={draw,red}` is defined, then calling `red drawing` executes `\tikzset{draw,red}` (sort of, actually it's `pgfkeys`).  So we simulate this by defining a key that executes `\tikzset` on whatever it is passed.  So `apply style={do,something,and,something,else}` will execute `\tikzset{do,something,and,something,else}`.  On its own, this isn't all that useful.  But when combined with the `/.expand once` key handler we can pass it a macro, get that macro expanded once, and then execute the style it contains.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{%
  apply style/.code={%
    \tikzset{#1}%
  }
}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\path \foreach \x/\content/\style in {%
  0/a/draw,
  1/b/{draw,red},
  2/c/{circle,draw=blue},
  3/d/draw%
} {
  node[apply style/.expand once=\style] at (\x,0) {\content}
} ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I really like this solution. It's the least overhead and leaves the loop almost un-modified :)

Comment: I've tried almost the same `apply style=\style` option with `ecode` and I don't understand why `\tikzset{apply style/.ecode={\noexpand\tikzset\noexpand{#1}}}` refuses to work.

Comment: Ah scratch that. Now I have it with regular `/.code` and `\expandafter`'s which is still lengthy than your solution.

Comment: @percusse: `.ecode` is effective at key definition time, not when the key is called. Even `.estyle` won't help you in that case.

Answer (score 16):

Use indirect styles numbered (perhaps more verbose but flexible):

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \tikzset{
    s0/.style={draw},
    s1/.style={draw,red},
    s2/.style={circle,draw=blue},
    s3/.style={draw},
  }
  \foreach \x/\content in {%
    0/a,
    1/b,
    2/c,
    3/d%
  } {
    \node[s\x] at (\x,0) {\content};
  };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 12):

Personally I always use the next method  and in a lot of cases I use   `\protected@edef` with LaTeX. With the next method you can use `\path node ... node ... ;`.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
 % \makeatletter\let\protectededef\protected@edef   not useful here but It' sometimes  
 % interesting
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \path 
    \foreach \x/\content/\style in {0/a/draw,
                                    1/b/{draw,red},
                                    2/c/{draw,circle,blue},
                                    3/d/draw}{
  \pgfextra{\edef\tmp{   % or \pgfextra{\protectededef\tmp{
  node[\style] at (\x,0) {\content}}}
  \tmp
  };
  \end{tikzpicture}  
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I think this would also work with only `\edef` (without protection).

Comment: @percusse Yes you are right! in a lot of cases, I need `\protected@edef` so it's always my first attempt.

Answer (score 10):

You can stick with your method. With a slight modification, it works.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \foreach \x/\content/\style in {%
    0/a/draw,
    1/b/{draw=red},
    2/c/{circle,draw=blue},
    3/d/draw
  }{
    \edef\x{\noexpand\node[\style] at (\x,0) {\content}}\x;
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

And PolGab's solution is:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[0/.style=draw,1/.style={draw=red},
    2/.style={circle,draw=blue},3/.style=draw]
  \foreach \x/\content in {0/a, 1/b, 2/c, 3/d}{
    \node[\x] at (\x,0) {\content};
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**EDIT (2012/07/22)**

Expanding on Andrew Stacey's solution, here is another one. Using `+` to list the keys eliminates the need for braces. The code can be generalized to take any symbol in place of `+`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\makeatletter
\def\replaceplus#1{\xreplaceplus#1+\@nil}
\def\xreplaceplus#1+#2\@nil{%
  \ifcat$\detokenize{#2}$\expandafter\@firstoftwo\else\expandafter\@secondoftwo\fi
  {\unexpanded{#1}}{\xreplaceplus#1,#2\@nil}%
}
\newcommand*\tikzexpanded[2]{%
  \begingroup
  \def\reserved@a##1#1##2##3\@nil{%
    \ifx\@nnil##2\def\x{#2}\else\edef\x{##2{#2}}\fi
  }%
  \reserved@a
    xx{\@iden}x0{\unexpanded}x1{\unexpanded\expandafter}%
    x2{\unexpanded\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter}#1{\@nnil}\@nil
  \edef\x{\expandafter\replaceplus\expandafter{\x}}%
  \edef\x{\endgroup\noexpand\tikzset{\unexpanded\expandafter{\x}}}\x
}
\tikzset{%
  use style/.code={\tikzset{#1}},
  use style expanded/.code={\tikzexpanded{xx}{#1}},
  use style expand once/.code={\tikzexpanded{x1}{#1}},
  use style expand twice/.code={\tikzexpanded{x2}{#1}}
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\path \foreach \x/\content/\style in{%
  0/a/draw,
  1/b/draw + red,
  2/c/circle + draw=blue,
  3/d/draw
}{
  node[use style expand once=\style] at (\x,0) {\content}
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can I use the same for a `\path node ... node ... node` command?

Comment: @knittl with my method you can use ` \path node .. node ..  ;`

Answer (score 4):

I have been using some keys that use the same mechanism as described in the answer by Loop Space. The user syntax is simpler and truthful to the key-value method. It solves more general questions, by expanding a *value* once, twice or completely before processing it as a *key*. The example in the question is slightly modified to include an example where expanding twice is necessary.

To answer the question, the following keys `set style` and  `expand style once` are enough. I include the key `expand style twice` to solve my modification of the example. I also include the key `expand style` which is useful when complete expansion is the goal and the number of expansions needed is not known.

You may want to check the minimal examples illustrating these facts [in my related answer here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/524113/204632).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{%
  set style/.style={#1},
  expand style/.style={%completely expands the <value> of its argument (using \edef) before processing the result as a <key>
    set style/.expanded={#1}% needs braces around the argument
  },
  expand style once/.style={% expands the <value> of its argument once before processing the result as a <key>
    set style/.expand once={#1}% needs braces around the argument
  },
  expand style twice/.style={% expands the <value> of its argument twice before processing the result as a <key>
    set style/.expand twice={#1}% needs braces around the argument
  }
}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\def\mystyle{fill=yellow}
\path \foreach \x/\content/\style in {%
  0/a/draw,
  1/b/{draw,red},
  2/c/{circle,draw=blue},
  3/d/\mystyle% \mystyle needs one more expansion after \style has been expanded once.
} {
  node[expand style=\style] at (\x,0) {\content}
} ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```