# Expansion problems with pgfkeys

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros, expansion, pgfkeys

I'm using `pgfkeys`, and a fairly adventurous syntax in which the values for some keys contain additional key/value pairs. (For instance, the value of the `nodes` key is a list of pairs, and the second component of each pair is a key-value list.)

I get a compilation error whenever I put anything too fancy into the `label` key. The code below works fine as-is, but if I replace `2+2` with `2+\sqrt{2}`, it breaks. I think it's a macro-expansion problem. How can I arrange it that the contents of the `label` key does *not* get expanded until it needs to be?

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\makeatletter

\pgfkeys{/wickerson/.cd,
  % The following two lines are from:
  % http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/85637/86
  execute style/.style = {#1},
  execute macro/.style = {execute style/.expand once=#1},
  left/.code=            {\xdef\wickerson@left{#1}},
  top/.code=             {\xdef\wickerson@top{#1}},
  label/.code=           {\gdef\wickerson@label{#1}},
  nodes/.code=           {\xdef\wickerson@nodes{#1}},
  colour/.code=          {\xdef\wickerson@colour{#1}},
}

\newcommand\myDiagram[1][]{%
  \pgfkeys{/wickerson/.cd,colour=black,nodes={},#1}
  \node[text=\wickerson@colour] at (0,0) {My Diagram...};
  \foreach \i/\values in \wickerson@nodes {
    \pgfkeys{/wickerson/.cd,left=0,top=0,label={},%
      execute macro=\values}
    \node[shape=circle,draw=black]
      at (\wickerson@left, \wickerson@top) 
      {\wickerson@label};
  }
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[x=1mm,y=-1mm]
\myDiagram[% 
  colour=red, %
  nodes={%
    a/{left=0,top=10,label={$2+2$}}, %
    b/{left=15,top=10,label={$\log 4$}}%
  }%
]
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: You can add `\noexpand` before the `\sqrt`, but I guess that's not the solution you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks Jake. Yeah, I guess I'm hoping for something that will apply `\noexpand` to everything in the label, so to speak.

Comment: In the MWE you neither need global assignments nor expanded ones. In each of the keys a simple `\def` should suffice. Then there also won't be an error with `$2+\srqt{2}$`

Comment: @cgnieder This is probably an answer.  Also, with eTeX, `\edef\foo{\unexpanded{#1}}` is slightly better than `\def\foo{#1}`, because it will correctly escape macro parameter characters `#` that are given inside the key, for even wilder labels.

Comment: The specific problem is that `nodes` is expanded, not `label`.

Comment: @RyanReich Aha! I haven't tried it yet, but I think you've hit the nail on the head. Thanks.

Comment: The adventure is not the additional key=value syntax but using existing names for your keys. Even if you fix this, 67 other issues would pop up if somehow you forget to change directory to `wickerson` family or changing directory is delayed.

Comment: @percusse Oh. Hm. I thought the whole point of the directory structure in `pgfkeys` was so that you *could* use existing names like `label` for your keys!

Comment: You could indeed. That's the adventure :)

Comment: @percusse I would not consider that a problem.  In fact, it's sort of a feature, if you want to "intercept" existing keys to add functionality to them in a transparent manner.

Comment: @RyanReich It is indeed but `pgfplots` has that feature too and sometimes it is really difficult to differentiate the TikZ family from the `pgfplots` family especially with interoperation say drawing features and plot features.

Comment: @JohnWickerson If you are going to use it extensively you might switch to `/.store in` and `/.estore in` keys to avoid those problems.

Comment: @percusse How would that avoid those problems?

Comment: You won't be defining as you do with the `/.code`, it's a little less tedious work and easier to maintain.

Comment: @percusse Yes, I see. And the `estore`/`store` syntax makes it a little clearer what one is trying to achieve. Thanks for the suggestion. By the way, I realise that I don't understand what you meant by your earlier comment about changing directory being delayed - could you say a little more about that?

Comment: I've tried to make it a little clearer in your newer question. If the directory cannot be changed then all your custom styles will obtain their original meaning and things would get difficult to debug.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just to confirm that **[cgnieder's comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/5049/cgnieder)** and **[Ryan Reich's explanation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/116352/expansion-problems-with-pgfkeys#comment257986_116352)** were right on target. I have managed to fix my code and understand the problem too. Thanks folks!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\makeatletter

\pgfkeys{/wickerson/.cd,
  % The following two lines are from:
  % https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/85637/86
  execute style/.style = {#1},
  execute macro/.style = {execute style/.expand once=#1},
  left/.code=            {\def\wickerson@left{#1}},
  top/.code=             {\def\wickerson@top{#1}},
  label/.code=           {\def\wickerson@label{#1}},
  nodes/.code=           {\def\wickerson@nodes{#1}},
  colour/.code=          {\def\wickerson@colour{#1}},
}

\newcommand\myDiagram[1][]{%
  \pgfkeys{/wickerson/.cd,colour=black,nodes={},#1}
  \node[text=\wickerson@colour] at (0,0) {My Diagram...};
  \foreach \i/\values in \wickerson@nodes {
    \pgfkeys{/wickerson/.cd,left=0,top=0,label={},%
      execute macro=\values}
    \node[shape=circle,draw=black]
      at (\wickerson@left, \wickerson@top) 
      {\wickerson@label};
  }
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[x=1mm,y=-1mm]
\myDiagram[% 
  colour=red, %
  nodes={%
    a/{left=0,top=10,label={$\sqrt{2}+2$}}, %
    b/{left=15,top=10,label={$\log 4$}}%
  }%
]
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: What are `\i`, `a`, `b` doing in your scheme? Also, the key `execute style` seems redundant.

Comment: @Ahmed if I may answer for John: I expect that `a` and `b` (as stored in `\i`) are intended to be used as node names eventually.  As for `execute style`, it *is* necessary to have a key to "hang" the `.expand once` handler on, since the result of a handler is always passed up to the parent key.

Comment: @RyanReich: What of `execute macro/.expand once=#1`?

Answer (score 3):

Here is a solution with *skeyval* package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{skeyval}[2013/05/01]
\makeatletter
\directkeys{%
  .family=wickerson,
  .holder prefix=wic@,
  .define keys={%
    .cmd/left/0,
    .cmd/top/0,
    .cmd/label//,
    .cmd/colour/black,
    .zcmd/title colour/black,
    .ord/nodes//
      \skvifblankTF{#1}{}{%
        \node[text=\wic@titlecolour] at (0,0) {My Diagram ...};
        \edef\tempa{\unexpanded{#1}}%
        \skvstripouterbraces{1}\tempa
        \newforeach [expand list once] \x in \tempa {%
          % Use the parameter rep of \x:
          \skvsetkeys{wickerson}{##1}%
          \node[shape=circle,draw=\wic@colour] at (\wic@left,\wic@top){\wic@label};
        }%
      },
  },
  % Allow 'color' to be a clone of 'colour':
  .link=color/colour,
}
\newcommand\myDiagram[1][]{%
  \directkeys{%
    .family=wickerson,
    .set keys={nodes,left,top,label,colour,title colour},
    .set keys={#1}
  }%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=1mm,y=-1mm]
\myDiagram[%
  title colour=green,
  nodes={
    {color=red,left=0,top=10,label={$\sqrt{2}+2$}},
    {color=blue,left=15,top=10,label={$\log 4$}}
  }%
]
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Note: I don't have the jpeg, png, tiff, gif or bmp format of output that this site is insisting on.