# How to .append to a value and retrieve it using .store in macro

Tags: pgfkeys

I'm learning `pgfkeys` and trying to use it for key-value argument handling.

I'm trying to set a style using it. For it, I defined a macro `\mystyle` to handle it, and use the same technique as in [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/85647/7561) to solve the execution of the style. Now, if I want to add more code to the argument using `.append`, the macro doesn't reflect the changes on it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\pgfkeys{
  /test/.cd,
  my style/.store in=\mystyle,
  my style/.default={draw,color=cyan,},
  my style,
  % helpers to get execution on styles
  % https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/85647/7561
  /tikz/.cd,
  execute style/.style = {#1},
  execute macro/.style = {execute style/.expand once=#1},%
}

\newcommand{\makenode}[2][]{
\pgfkeys{/test/.cd,#1}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[execute macro=\mystyle]{#2};
\end{tikzpicture}
}


\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

\makenode{testing}
\makenode[my style={draw,color=blue,line width=5pt,}]{testing blue}
% this should be yellow, with thin line
\makenode[my style/.append={color=yellow,line width=1pt}]{testing blue}


\end{document}
```

From what I understood from the manual, the argument should be appended to the value of the key. So if I have in the value `<something>`, and I do `<key>/.append={<more>}`, the value in `<key>` should be `<something><more>`. But that isn't happening.

What am I missing?

Comment: Does http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/159856/  help?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not sure why you want to use `=`, `.append=` and `.default=` at the same time. The remaining is based on my guess.

- If you pass `[my style=\A]` to `\makenode`, the style list `\A` is applied.
- If you pass `[append my style=\B]` to `\makenode`, the style list `\B` is applied along with `draw,color=cyan`, your default.
- If you pass nothing to `\makenode`, the `\newcommand` inserts its default, `append my style={}`. That means nothing but only `draw,color=cyan` is applied.

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10]{standalone}
\pgfkeys{
  /test/.cd,
  my style/.style={
    /test/final style/.style={#1}
  },
  append my style/.style={
    /test/final style/.style={draw,color=cyan,#1}
  }
}
\newcommand{\makenode}[2][append my style={}]{
    \pgfkeys{/test/.cd,#1}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[/test/final style]{#2};
    \end{tikzpicture}
}
\begin{document}
    \makenode{testing}
    \makenode[my style={}]{testing plain}
    \makenode[my style={fill=blue,line width=5pt}]{testing blue}
    \makenode[append my style={fill=yellow,line width=1pt}]{testing yellow}
\end{document}
```

Hence

- for `testing`, it is drawn in cyan, your default;
- for `testing plain`, all styles are reset;
- for `testing blue`, `draw` and `color=cyan` is covered so no drawing happens;

  - (Otherwise it should be much taller due to `line width=5pt`)
- for `testing yellow`, filling happens along with drawing.

### Too Long. Short?

The essential problem, with `cyan` being the default, is what you expect the following do?

- `\makenode[blue]{testing}`
- `\makenode[]{testing}`

This sounds stupid: The first node appears in blue while the second obeys the **default** color... But wait, what is the **default** now? Blue or cyan?

The answer may be blue because writing `my style=blue` or `my style/.style=blue` causes PGF to forget the old value/old style. The only way to keep a global **default** is `my style/.default={cyan}`, which assumes `my style` to be an **action**. An **action** is declared by `.code` and neither `.append` nor `.append style` is applicable.

In conclusion, `=`, `.append`, and `.default` are not designed to work together. Maybe there is a tricky way to get over it. But sooner or later you will confuse PGF... and yourself.

Comment: I'm learning `pgfkeys`, and in the page 897 in the manual it says that `.append` should work like `.append style` but for the value. Since, I may need to use the same for several keys, I thought that the way to go was to use a similar style as the default for styles, i.e., `.append style`. And regarding the use of `=`, `.default`, can you elaborate why is not good to use them?

Comment: @adn It is not **not good**. The only reason it that they are not designed to work together. Have a look at my edit.

Comment: your `/.code` handlers can be written simply as `/.style` because they just set keys and `/.style` takes care of the family switches for you too.

Comment: I knew it is not minimal!! thanks @percusse